# Как из числового сделать ассоциативный массив?

Tags: php

На сервере получаю массив, длина его может быть разной:

```
       array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "1"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "Color3"
        [2]=>
        string(11) "ASTM D15003"
        [3]=>
        string(3) "552"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "1"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "Color4"
        [2]=>
        string(11) "ASTM D15004"
        [3]=>
        string(1) "4"
      }
    }
```

Как сделать, чтобы было так:

```
        array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        "print"=> "1"
        "inspection"=> "Color3"
        "method"=> "ASTM D15003"
        "result"=>"552"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        "print"=> "1"
        "inspection"=> "Color3"
        "method"=> "ASTM D15003"
        "result"=>"552"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
$arr = [
    ['1', 'Color3', 'AStM D15003', '552'],
    ['1', 'Color4', 'AStM D15004', '4'],
];

$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $temp = [];
    $temp['print'] = $item[0];
    $temp['inspection'] = $item[1];
    $temp['method'] = $item[2];
    $temp['result'] = $item[3];
    array_push($result, $temp);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: спасибо! лайк сразу)

Comment: @junior ))) Рад помочь. Если что-то останется не понятным - смело спрашивайте, добавлю пояснения )

Answer (score 0):

для преобразования массива в новый вид обычно используют функцию `array_map`. Для генерация массива известными ключами и значениями используют `array_combine`.

```
$result = array_map(fuction($v){
                  return array_combine(['print',....], $v);
             }, $input);
```

без combine можете и просто вернуть новый элемент

```
return ['print' => $v[0], .....];
```

или предварительно развернуть массив в переменные, это может быть удобное, если также следует какую-то логику выполнить,чтобы не таскать с собой индексы эти.

```
[$p, $i, $m, $r] = $v;
return ['print' => $p, ....];
```